# Format tab icon size in R flexdashboard

Tags: flexdashboard

I've built an R flexdasboard with tabs. I've added icons to the dashboard with:

```
a_tab_name {data-icon="fa-calendar"}
=====================================
```

I would like to increase the size of the icon. This can be done in a Shny app with
 `icon("calendar", "fa-3x")`
which would cause the "calendar" icon in the "fa" icon library to be rendered 3x default size.

is it possible to do this in the flexdashboad tab syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add some inline CSS to the `.active` attribute. Using CSS font-size control.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```
<style>
.active {
  font-size:25px;
}
</style>

a_tab_name {data-icon="fa-calendar"}
=====================================


Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```
````

Before...
[image]

After...
[image]

Comment: for me it did not work... i guess, you might have to call the class a_tab_name {.active data-icon="fa-calendar"}