# Removing Empty Spaces in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-visualization

I found this tutorial here that I want to follow: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jjallaire/htmlwidgets-showcase-storyboard/htmlwidgets-showcase-storyboard.html

I would like to try and find a way to remove the "empty spaces" that appear in the tabs (e.g. remove the spaces below the red line):

[image]

Is there a way to do this in R? I tried to follow the advice recommended in this post over here ([Format tab icon size in R flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756174/format-tab-icon-size-in-r-flexdashboard)) and manually change the font size in hopes that this would work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```
<style>
.active {
  font-size:15px;
}
</style>

a_tab_name {data-icon="fa-calendar"}
=====================================


Column {data-width=150}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```
````

This seemed to have worked - but is there an automatic way to instruct R to remove all empty spaces in these tabs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height: auto`

---

````
---
title: "HTML Widgets Showcase"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{css}
.storyboard-nav .sbframelist ul li {
    height: auto;
}
```


### Leaflet is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and zooming along with various annotations.


### d3heatmap creates interactive D3 heatmaps including support for row/column.


### Dygraphs provides rich facilities for charting time-series data in R and includes support for many interactive features.


### Plotly provides bindings to the plotly.js library
````

---

Which looks like,

[image: flex_dash_board]

---